# Docker-compose, Swag error: "Your DockerHost is most likely running an outdated version of libseccomp"

Tags: docker, docker-compose, raspberry-pi, reverse-proxy

I am not sure what is wrong. I just start to learn docker and I am trying to do a project with a reverse proxy. I am running docker & docker-compose on an RPI 4 at home. However, I am running into a problem after I created and run the docker-compose.yml with the following information:

```
version: '2.1'
services:
  duckdns:
    image: linuxserver/duckdns
    container_name: duckdns
    environment:
      - PUID=1000 #optional
      - PGID=1000 #optional
      - TZ=America/New_York
      - SUBDOMAINS=My_SubDomain,
      - TOKEN=myToken
      - LOG_FILE=false #optional
    volumes:
      - /home/pi/compose/data/duckdns/config:/config #optional
    restart: unless-stopped

  swag:
    image: linuxserver/swag
    container_name: swag
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
    environment:
      - PUID=1000
      - PGID=1000
      - TZ=America/New_York
      - URL=My_SUBDOMAIN.duckdns.org
      - SUBDOMAINS=www,
      - VALIDATION=duckdns
      - DNSPLUGIN=cloudflare #optional
      - PROPAGATION= #optional
      - DUCKDNSTOKEN=MY_TOKEN
      - EMAIL= #optional
      - ONLY_SUBDOMAINS=false #optional
      - EXTRA_DOMAINS= #optional
      - STAGING=false #optional
    volumes:
      - /home/pi/compose/data/swag/config:/config
    ports:
      - 443:443
      - 80:80 #optional
    restart: unless-stopped
```

My duckdns is up and running and I open the ports on my router. (Is that a good idea)

Then I run my Swag with sudo docker-compose up -d swag && sudo docker logs -f swag

shortly after the error came up:

[image]

```
[cont-init.d] 10-adduser: exited 0.
[cont-init.d] 20-config: executing...
[cont-init.d] 20-config: exited 0.
[cont-init.d] 30-keygen: executing...
generating self-signed keys in /config/keys, you can replace these with your own keys if required
Generating a RSA private key
..........+++++
...........+++++
writing new private key to '/config/keys/cert.key'
-----
3069969296:error:0D0D90AD:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_TIME_adj:error getting time:crypto/asn1/a_time.c:330:
[cont-init.d] 30-keygen: exited 1.
[cont-finish.d] executing container finish scripts...
[cont-finish.d] done.
[s6-finish] waiting for services.
[s6-finish] sending all processes the TERM signal.
[s6-finish] sending all processes the KILL signal and exiting.
[s6-init] making user provided files available at /var/run/s6/etc...exited 0.
[s6-init] ensuring user provided files have correct perms...exited 0.
[fix-attrs.d] applying ownership & permissions fixes...
[fix-attrs.d] done.
[cont-init.d] executing container initialization scripts...
[cont-init.d] 01-envfile: executing...
[cont-init.d] 01-envfile: exited 0.
[cont-init.d] 10-adduser: executing...
usermod: no changes

-------------------------------------
          _         ()
         | |  ___   _    __
         | | / __| | |  /  \
         | | \__ \ | | | () |
         |_| |___/ |_|  \__/


Brought to you by linuxserver.io
-------------------------------------

To support the app dev(s) visit:
Certbot: https://supporters.eff.org/donate/support-work-on-certbot

To support LSIO projects visit:
https://www.linuxserver.io/donate/
-------------------------------------
GID/UID
-------------------------------------
User uid:    1000
User gid:    1000
-------------------------------------
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@

Your DockerHost is most likely running an outdated version of libseccomp

To fix this, please visit https://docs.linuxserver.io/faq#libseccomp

Some apps might not behave correctly without this

@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@

[cont-init.d] 10-adduser: exited 0.
[cont-init.d] 20-config: executing...
[cont-init.d] 20-config: exited 0.
[cont-init.d] 30-keygen: executing...
generating self-signed keys in /config/keys, you can replace these with your own keys if required
Generating a RSA private key
......................+++++
.........+++++
writing new private key to '/config/keys/cert.key'
-----
3069641616:error:0D0D90AD:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_TIME_adj:error getting time:crypto/asn1/a_time.c:330:
[cont-init.d] 30-keygen: exited 1.
[cont-finish.d] executing container finish scripts...
[cont-finish.d] done.
[s6-finish] waiting for services.
[s6-finish] sending all processes the TERM signal.
[s6-finish] sending all processes the KILL signal and exiting.
```

I check the link after "DockerHost is most likely running an outdated version of libseccomp" but I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Any ideas will be really appreciated.

---

I delete the containers, then tried both of the troubleshooting you mention but I keep getting the same error. Do I need to have ports 80 and 443 open on my router? I have them disable at the moment.

Latest error after doing *sudo docker-compose up -d swag && sudo docker logs -f swag*

```
    Creating swag ... done
    [s6-init] making user provided files available at /var/run/s6/etc...exited 0.
    [s6-init] ensuring user provided files have correct perms...exited 0.
    [fix-attrs.d] applying ownership & permissions fixes...
    [fix-attrs.d] done.
    [cont-init.d] executing container initialization scripts...
    [cont-init.d] 01-envfile: executing...
    [cont-init.d] 01-envfile: exited 0.
    [cont-init.d] 10-adduser: executing...
    
    -------------------------------------
              _         ()
             | |  ___   _    __
             | | / __| | |  /  \
             | | \__ \ | | | () |
             |_| |___/ |_|  \__/
    
    
    Brought to you by linuxserver.io
    -------------------------------------
    
    To support the app dev(s) visit:
    Certbot: https://supporters.eff.org/donate/support-work-on-certbot
    
    To supp

ort LSIO projects visit:
    https://www.linuxserver.io/donate/
    -------------------------------------
    GID/UID
    -------------------------------------
    
    User uid:    1000
    User gid:    1000
    -------------------------------------
    
    
    @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
    
    Your DockerHost is most likely running an outdated version of libseccomp
    
    To fix this, please visit https://docs.linuxserver.io/faq#libseccomp
    
    Some apps might not behave correctly without this
    
    @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
    
    [cont-init.d] 10-adduser: exited 0.
    [cont-init.d] 20-config: executing...
    [cont-init.d] 20-config: exited 0.
    [cont-init.d] 30-keygen: executing...
    generating self-signed keys in /config/keys, you can replace these with your own keys if required
    Generating a RSA private key
    ................................................+++++
    .......................................................................+++++
    writing new private key to '/config/keys/cert.key'
    -----
    3069698960:error:0D0D90AD:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_TIME_adj:error getting time:crypto/asn1/a_time.c:330:
    [cont-init.d] 30-keygen: exited 1.
    [cont-finish.d] executing container finish scripts...
    [cont-finish.d] done.
    [s6-finish] waiting for services.
    [s6-finish] sending all processes the TERM signal.
    [s6-finish] sending all processes the KILL signal and exiting.
```

Answer (score 10):

I encountered this error as well when upgrading to the new Swag image on Raspberry Pi. They address this issue on the [Linux Server FAQ page](https://docs.linuxserver.io/faq#libseccomp).

Their suggestion to manually install the updated library with dpkg worked:

```
wget http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libs/libseccomp/libseccomp2_2.5.1-1_armhf.deb
sudo dpkg -i libseccomp2_2.5.1-1_armhf.deb
```

The package address in the wget command is correct as of 4/13/21. You can find the latest version by browsing [here](http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libs/libseccomp/).

An alternate solution would be to add the backport repos for Debian Buster:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 04EE7237B7D453EC 648ACFD622F3D138
echo "deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/buster-backports.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt install -t buster-backports libseccomp2
```

You can also see the other suggestions for resolving this issue on the [FAQ page](https://docs.linuxserver.io/faq#libseccomp).

Comment: Thank you, I manually install the updated library with dpkg twice but the error is still there. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Im not an expert at all

Comment: It might be a dummy question. what I need to do to fix this problem is to copy and paste these two lines of code (the wget .... and then the sudo dpkg...). right?

Comment: @JuanDiaz Sorry, I just updated the command to reflect a newer version of libseccomp which had succeeded for me last time. And yes, that is how you're supposed to run it.

Comment: @JuanDiaz Sure! You should definitely be running these on the host, not the docker container.

Comment: Thank you, do I suppose to run it inside the docker container on the @pi user?

Comment: perfect.thank you. I just kill all the containers and I am going to try it again. :D

Comment: I am still having problems. I just edit the question with the latest error which is pretty much the same thing